# how to deal with strict type checking in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write my first programm in Haskell (it's quite simple one)
for checking if the given number is prime:

```
prime :: Num n=> n -> Bool
prime x=smz[x `mod` a > 0 | a<-[2..(round(sqrt x))]] where
        smz :: [Bool]->Bool
        smz [] = True
        smz (c:cs)=c && (smz cs)
```

but I've encountered bunch of errors. Could someone give me correct version of my code (without changing my idea)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please always include any error information in the question, and generally follow [the guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Else you make answering much more cumbersome than it needs to be (and your questions will probably be downvoted, making them less visible).

Comment: Well if you encounter a buch of errors, doesn't it makes much sense to *include* the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `smz` function already exists in the standard Prelude and it's called `and`.
2. `mod` can only be used with `Integral`, `mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`, that means that you can't use an x that has to be a `Floating` due to `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`, therefore you are left in a situation where your x has to be both an Integral (like Int, for example) and a Floating point number. That's impossible!

   There's a solution for that. You have to convert from either one in either place. I suggest you convert `fromIntegral` before you shove it to `sqrt`. That also means that your function's type signature will change, and you should simply remove the current one and see for yourself.

Other than that you might want to keep your `where` clause *under* your function declaration like so:

```
foo x = ...
   where
     baz n = ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Compilation errors in GHC contain the actual description, also position in source. Some newer ghc versions also print a snippet of code. Also there are additional information added to the error message, so it overall looks rather scary. But the actual error is in first lines. Simplest ones are type mismatch which say like "expected this, got that". In complicated cases you might have to check documentation, Google or SO.

It is often better to start with the first error. Sometimes they are obvious to fix. Sometimes they make you reconsider your design. After fixing the error compile again and pick the next one. Continue until all errors are fixed.

Some also advise to not write a lot of code first then compile and get a lot of errors but write as little as possible, then compile. So that you get fewer errors at each step.